# WPF - how to show in ICollectionView Bitmapimages?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a `List<Book>` which contains a `BitmapImage`.

And I have a `DataGrid` which gets it's information from a `ICollectionView` which is initialized like that:

```
ObservableCollection<Book> OCBooks = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
CollectionViewSource BooksCollection;
Predicate<object> yourCostumFilter;
ICollectionView Itemlist;
Book b = Book.Instance;
```

.
.
.

```
private void InitializeObservableCollection()
        {
            foreach (var item in ChangeBooksImagesToBitmapImage(b.GetBooksList()))
                OCBooks.Add(item);
            BooksCollection = new CollectionViewSource { Source = OCBooks };
            Itemlist = BooksCollection.View;
            DG_BooksList.ItemsSource = Itemlist;
        }
```

.
.
.

```
private List<Book> ChangeBooksImagesToBitmapImage(List<Book> list)
        {
            // takes a Books list with imgURLs and returns one with BitmapImage
            List<Book> newbl = new List<Book>();
            foreach (var book in list)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(book.ImgURL))
                {
                    BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
                    logo.BeginInit();
                    logo.UriSource = new Uri(book.ImgURL);
                    logo.DecodePixelHeight = 25;
                    logo.DecodePixelWidth = 25;
                    logo.EndInit();
                    newbl.Add(
                        new Book(
                            book.BookName,
                            book.Genre,
                            DateTime.Parse(book.Published.ToShortDateString()),
                            book.Publisher,
                            logo,
                            book.Quantity));
                }
                else
                    newbl.Add(book);
            }
            return newbl;
        }
```

I previously used just a regular list of and bound it column by column to the `DG_BooksList` so I'll be able to manipulate the columns and it worked.

And when I wanted to create a filter for the list'I understood that using the `ICollectionView` might be a better way to go.

Only now I don't know how to manipulate each single column in the `DataGrid` When It's automatically giving it the information.

I tried to look for an answer but couldn't find, how do I manipulate single columns in the `DataGrid` like that and how do I show a `BitmapImage` in the `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Book type contains public property Logo and also implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.. you can use DataGridTemplateColumn and specify dataTemplate for it

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Logo">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Logo}" Height="25" Width="25"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: @Clemens ok but how do io do that in the datagrid, the information from the ICollectionView of the logo wont be desplayed?

Comment: @Yuval Peretz In Book Logo is public property ? Is it Book implemented INotifyPropertyChanged ? Can you share

Comment: @Anton I'm very sorry for that, I don't usually ask here questions..
so about the logo, it is declared in the Book class yes.

and this is the XAML of the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid
                    x:Name="DG_BooksList"
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    
                </DataGrid>
```

all changes to the datagrid are happening withing the C# it self..

if doing it insind of the XAML is possible then I'll do it there.

Comment: Yuval Peretz you need also look on Output window during debugging if you will have some binding exceptions - it will be showing there.